# Voltage Divider For DC Fan

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, fan

I have been researching various ways to control DC fans and out of curiosity bought a fan that has a 4-position switch with off, low, medium, and high settings. I thought that a voltage divider should not be used as a power supply.

I drew the schematic for it (2 surface mount resistors and 4 position switch) that includes my measured voltages.  I think that it is putting 1.87V across R1 (0.27W) at the low setting and 1.13V across R2 (0.21W) at the medium setting.  I left it running for hours and there was no obvious heat build-up.  How did they get away with this?  The ground plane and solder pads are pretty big, could that account for its performance?[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you have there is not exactly a voltage divider.

You need some power into the motor to keep the fan running, and to beat friction and such, so the motor does dissipate as a resistor, but the equation \$ V = RI \$ is not true for a DC motor.

When you power a motor, at first it is not moving, and the current through it is determined by the winding resistance. As the rotor starts spinning, a new voltage rises: the back EMF. Basically the motor behaves like a voltage source, and its voltage rises until it equals the voltage outside, minus the drop on the winding resistance.

If you put a resistance in series with the external voltage source, the current through it will lower the voltage and the source will appear as a lower voltage source, so the motor will spin slower.

As per your questions, I am not surprised you felt no heat rise. The power dissipated is very low, and unless they used exceptionally small resistors, I expect no significant temp rise.

As per "how do they get away with this"... It's cheap. Like dirt cheap. From idea to gerbers it maybe takes a full hour to do that design.

Comment: Yeah, I would call this using current limiting resistors rather than a voltage divider

Comment: Thank you, that really answers what was puzzling me - it doesn't look like a voltage divider unless the fan is a resistive load and I could never get a reading on its resistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, it is not an efficient way of controlling a fan. However, cost calculation might explain that tradeoff.

For example, in a car, you could justify that a few extra wasted Watts are negligeable compared to the actual power output of the engine and all the ancillaries. If you save a lot of money on manufacturing, then perhaps it is worth the reduced effeciency.

For the board itself, currents are not significant enough to generate tons of heat especially if the traces, planes and pads are big. The resistors on the other hand needs to be speced accordingly. But, the traces will generate almost no heat at all.

You can check this calculator out if you want a rough estimate of what could be the equivalent resistor: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/trace-resistance-calculator/

Comment: Thanks - I suppose for my own projects I'll stick with PWM.  I really need to just buy the Maxim ICs designed for fan control and call it a day.

Comment: Learning wise, you are totally right!